# How do I create a random word title?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x, transitions

I really don't know what is the best way to phrase this. But basically what I want is to have a single word on the screen, e.g. AUGUST.

So when the title first starts, all 6 letters will be constantly switching to random letters. Then slowly the letter in first position will stop, so in the example A will stop, then followed by U, G, U, S, T. Essentially it is a bunch of randomly changing letters in place that slowly reveal themselves to form a word.

Am working with Final Cut Pro, have Motion but not sure how to use it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Someone recently asked on another forum in another context for the similar effect, so I created a [JavaScript implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/oe57g58m/) for them, runs in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to what I was looking for in this video, by accident. Leaving it here so others may find it in the future.

I was able to get all letters to generate at once by selecting Custom in the behaviour of how the letters were generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add for anyone on After Effects you can very quickly and easily add a character offset.

[image]

[image]